# What consumes more storage space - boost::dynamic_bitset<> or raw storage?

Tags: c++, boost, boolean, data-storage

I have a program storage optimization question.

I have, let say 4096 "knots" stored in a:

```
  boost::dynamic_bitset<>
```

I am now considering refactoring my program and build a `CKnot` class which will contain a `bool`.

The question is what will consume more space:

- boost::dynamic_bitset<> ( 4096 , false );
- CKnot Knot[4096] //contain one bool

Thanks

Comment: Its not going to make a whole lot of difference. The static array method is going to be faster because it will fit into 1 page of memory!!

Comment: if i will increases the number of knots from 4096 (= 2^12) to 2^30, which is my end goal. Will it them make a difference? or still not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bitset will be considerably smaller, as a bool in C++ must be at least a byte in size, whereas each bit in a bitset is exactly that, a bit.

Comment: In fact, bool in C++ is the same size as integer. To make it smaller you have to use bitfield, which can cut individual members to single bits, but the object containing them still has to be at least one byte.

Comment: @Jan sizeof(bool) is implementation defined - see C++ Standard 5.3.3. It is of integral type, but that does not been it must be the same size as ain integer, which I take to mean `int`.